# How to use view helpers with rails-api gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, backend, rails-api

I use [rails-api](https://github.com/spastorino/rails-api) and [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) gems to make api application. I don't want to put a lot of logic into rabl views but if that I want to extract it into helpers. Rails-api gem doesn't include helpers support (and thats ok) so **how I can enable helpers into my json views?(what middleware I need to include, which modules etc)**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the controller that renders the view you have to

1. include ActionController::Helpers and
2. provide your own Helper modules to the view using the 'helper' method

In my API application I created a RenderingController which acts as a superclass for all controllers that do render:

```
class RenderingController < ApplicationController
  include AbstractController::Layouts
  include AbstractController::Translation
  include ActionController::ImplicitRender
  include ActionController::Helpers

  helper ApplicationHelper, OtherHelper
end
```

Comment: Absolutely true but I include it in ```ApplicationController``` because I want to use my helpers in all views.

Comment: Can't you also just extend ActionController::Base?

Comment: You could, but then you would include a bunch of modules that you probably don't need.

Comment: How would you do this if you need the helper in a mailer?